# using rtf file as report layout in birt

Tags: birt

I've an .rtf file which contains the report layout. can i provide this rtf file as input to birt for creating a report layout ? I'm trying to use xml file as a datasource. but i dont want to create a new report layout since i've the old layout in rtf file. so is it possible to use the rtf file as design template in birt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

Yet there is something related to RTF found in BIRT (but doesn't work; see [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284323))

If you use a Dynamic Text filed you can set it's properties in order to contain RTF.
In the Properties Editor: Properties - Advanced - Content type - RTF